# Is it incorrect online version of EBNF standard, or incorrect the chapter's name by mr. Pattis?

Tags: grammar, bnf, ebnf

I am reading the *[EBNF: A Notation to Describe Syntax](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~pattis/misc/ebnf2.pdf)* chapter by mr. [Richard E. Pattis](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~pattis/). His material is very useful and clear for me. But before it I read the [ISO/IEC 14977 : 1996(E)](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/iso-14977.pdf) standard... I see EBNF notations and syntax by mr. Richard E. Pattis is not the same like ones in the standard. I don't understand the reason of this...

For example, standard writes:

> a) Terminal symbols of the language are quoted so that any character,
>   including one used in Extended BNF, can be defined as a terminal
>   symbol of the language being defined.

But mr. Pattis doesn't use the quotes in own samples. In addition, he uses unconvenient way for writting non-terminal symbols as terminal ones: for example the `|` char he puts into *a box* (it seems like a *border* around the char in MS Word). Usual text editors can't do it. Therefore this way is unconvenient.

Also, standard writes:

> d) Each rule has an explicit final character so that there is never
>   any ambiguity about where a rule ends.

But mr. Pattis doesn't use any final characters in own samples.

According the standard the "=" char is *defining-symbol*, but mr. Pattis uses the "⇐" ones instead of this.

etc

Chapter's code sample:

```
digit   ⇐ 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9
integer ⇐ [+|-]digit{digit}
```

For comparing: in the [ISO/IEC 14977 : 1996(E)](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/iso-14977.pdf) standard each digit is isolated by quotes and the semicolon is used as final character:

```
decimal digit = ’0’ | ’1’ | ’2’ | ’3’ | ’4’ | ’5’ | ’6’ | ’7’ | ’8’ | ’9’;
```

Existence of the "EBNF" word at the chapter's name confuses me... Maybe the "BNF" word must to be written  instead of the "EBNF" ones at the chapter's name? Or maybe I found incorrect variant of standard?

**Additional question:** somebody knows the addresses of forums where I can ask my questions about the EBNF and its standard? I found nothing still...

Best regards,
Andrey

Comment: [EBNF on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus–Naur_Form): "many variants of EBNF are in use ... Other EBNF variants use somewhat different syntactic conventions"

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know that alternatives also is naming EBNF. I expected _EBNF_ means only _EBNF by ISO/IEC 14977 : 1996(E)_, because exists the standard.

Comment: I wonder if there is any real use in a formalism defined and followed this vaguely.. I've been trying to find an EBNF validator, and only managed to find one tool that actually follows the standard ISO EBNF notation: a `bnf syntax checker` from [icosaedro](http://www.icosaedro.it/bnf_chk/).

Comment: that one is not ISO either... no support for concatenation by `,` or non-terminal names containing `-`(?)

Answer (score 0):

My tutorial is a first lecture that I give in my introduction to programming classes: I teach EBNF as a mini-programming language that includes named rules (like functions) and control structures (sequence, if, loop, recursion). Students learn to be language lawyers (determining whether strings match EBNF rules) and programmers (synthesizing EBNF rules from English descriptions, including positive and negative exemplars).

Therefore my goal is not to teach anyone the ISO standard, but to teach the simplest form of EBNF to absolute novices.

Rich Pattis

Comment: To all other reviewer may vote to close, he claimed to be the author of the book mentioned in the question.